# How to drop a constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

Using SQL Server 2008

Table1 has a constraint with the name `idx_u_customerinfo`.

I deleted `table1` directly (right click delete), I wrote a script for creating the table1 with same constraint name `idx_u_customerinfo`.

I'm getting an error

> There is already an object named 'idx_u_customerinfo' in the database.

I need to delete the constraint name, How to do this?

Comment: `delete` only removes the rows from the table. It does not drop the table.

Comment: What do you get when you run: `SELECT Name, type_desc FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N'idx_u_customerinfo'` ?

Comment: If you're writing a script to create the table and the index run it for the table part then remove the index, when you drop the table remember to drop the index before the table.

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER TABLE "table_name"
>   DROP [CONSTRAINT|INDEX] "CONSTRAINT_NAME";

So like: 
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT idx_u_customerinfo;

Comment: I alreay deleted the table, but constraint name is still showing

Comment: The constraint was saved so have you tried creating table1 again just to drop the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Either you did not actually drop `table1` or the index `idx_u_customerinfo` exists in another table. You can't have two tables in the same database with the same index name, so it's good practice to incorporate the table name into the index name, e.g. `idx_table1_customerinfo`.

This should give you all the information about this index to determine what to do next

```
SELECT tbl.name, idx.name, idx.type_desc
FROM sys.objects idx 
JOIN sys.objects tbl ON idx.parent_object_id = tbl.object_id
WHERE idx.name = N'idx_u_customerinfo'
```